# Change the image format of thumbnails created in word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-word-2013, wmf

I have noticed that thumbnails in Word 2013 are saved in emf format.  Thumbnails in Word 2007 are saved in wmf format.  Is there any way to configure Word 2013 to save in the wmf?

In fact are there any setting at all for controlling the size, format or resolution of thumbnails generated in any version of word?